# How to move Attribute Group at last on product edit page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, adminhtml, product-edit, attribute-group

In Magento admin I created a product attribute group.

I want to move this attribute group as last tab in product page in admin.

How Do I move this in last of all tabs ?

[image]

[image]

**Note :** Using drag-drop you can only move tab before inventory. I want this tab to move at last after all tab.

Comment: I got some thing related to sort in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs` `->setSortOrder()` in group collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copy** `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php` **To** `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php`

You have to add your custom logic in method `_prepareLayout()` inside `foreach ($groupCollection as $group)` loop and skip that group whichever you want based on group id or group name and add that group tab in last or at your position.

**file content**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * admin product edit tabs
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
    protected $_attributeTabBlock = 'adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('product_info_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('product_edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Information'));
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();

        if (!($setId = $product->getAttributeSetId())) {
            $setId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set', null);
        }

        if ($setId) {
            $groupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection')
                ->setAttributeSetFilter($setId)
                ->setSortOrder()
                ->load();
            $total=$groupCollection->count();
            $count=1;
            $last=null;
            foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
                if($count==$total)
                {
                    $last=$group;
                    break;
                }
                $count++;
                $attributes = $product->getAttributes($group->getId(), true);
                // do not add groups without attributes

                foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
                    if( !$attribute->getIsVisible() ) {
                        unset($attributes[$key]);
                    }
                }

                if (count($attributes)==0) {
                    continue;
                }

                $this->addTab('group_'.$group->getId(), array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                        'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                            ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                            ->toHtml()),
                ));
            }

            if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
                $this->addTab('inventory', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Inventory'),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                        ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_inventory')->toHtml()),
                ));
            }

            /**
             * Don't display website tab for single mode
             */
            if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
                $this->addTab('websites', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Websites'),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                        ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_websites')->toHtml()),
                ));
            }

            $this->addTab('categories', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/categories', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $this->addTab('related', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Related Products'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/related', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $this->addTab('upsell', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Up-sells'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/upsell', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $this->addTab('crosssell', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Cross-sells'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/crosssell', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));

            $storeId = 0;
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))->getId();
            }

            $alertPriceAllow = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/productalert/allow_price');
            $alertStockAllow = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/productalert/allow_stock');

            if (($alertPriceAllow || $alertStockAllow) && !$product->isGrouped()) {
                $this->addTab('productalert', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Alerts'),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                        ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_alerts', 'admin.alerts.products')->toHtml())
                ));
            }

            if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false) ) {
                if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Review')) {
                    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/catalog/reviews_ratings')){
                        $this->addTab('reviews', array(
                            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Reviews'),
                            'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/reviews', array('_current' => true)),
                            'class' => 'ajax',
                        ));
                    }
                }
                if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Tag')) {
                    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/catalog/tag')){
                        $this->addTab('tags', array(
                         'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Tags'),
                         'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/tagGrid', array('_current' => true)),
                         'class' => 'ajax',
                        ));

                        $this->addTab('customers_tags', array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Customers Tagged Product'),
                            'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/tagCustomerGrid', array('_current' => true)),
                            'class' => 'ajax',
                        ));
                    }
                }

            }

            /**
             * Do not change this tab id
             * @see Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs_Configurable
             * @see Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
             */
            if (!$product->isGrouped()) {
                $this->addTab('customer_options', array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Options'),
                    'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/options', array('_current' => true)),
                    'class' => 'ajax',
                ));
            }

            if($last)
            {
                $attributes = $product->getAttributes($last->getId(), true);
                // do not add groups without attributes

                foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
                    if( !$attribute->getIsVisible() ) {
                        unset($attributes[$key]);
                    }
                }

                if (count($attributes)==0) {
                    continue;
                }

                $this->addTab('group_'.$last->getId(), array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($last->getAttributeGroupName()),
                    'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                        'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($last)
                            ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                            ->toHtml()),
                ));
            }

        }
        else {
            $this->addTab('set', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Settings'),
                'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_settings')->toHtml()),
                'active'    => true
            ));
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Retrive product object from object if not from registry
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (!($this->getData('product') instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) {
            $this->setData('product', Mage::registry('product'));
        }
        return $this->getData('product');
    }

    /**
     * Getting attribute block name for tabs
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttributeTabBlock()
    {
        if (is_null(Mage::helper('adminhtml/catalog')->getAttributeTabBlock())) {
            return $this->_attributeTabBlock;
        }
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml/catalog')->getAttributeTabBlock();
    }

    public function setAttributeTabBlock($attributeTabBlock)
    {
        $this->_attributeTabBlock = $attributeTabBlock;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Translate html content
     *
     * @param string $html
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _translateHtml($html)
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/translate_inline')->processResponseBody($html);
        return $html;
    }
}
```